# Hopf-Rinow theorem simple question

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Being reading about the Hopf-Rinow theorem in the Do-Carmo book, I got a simple question. The statement is formulated this way:
Let $M$ be a Riemann manifold (connected); assertions are equivalent 
a)  $\exp_p$ is defined on all $T_p M$ 
b) $M$ is complete as metric space.

Consider closed (closed as a subset in $\Bbb R^n$ topology) and boarded manifold in $\Bbb R^n$, for example, half of a sphere. Obviously, it is complete as metric space, but $\exp_p$ isn't defined on all $T_p M$. If you need text, I will add screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

My question has already been answered, here is a link [Hopf-Rinow Theorem for Riemannian Manifolds with Boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404223/hopf-rinow-theorem-for-riemannian-manifolds-with-boundary?rq=1) . Sorry for my caralessness.